# NiFi Auth with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-nifi

Is it possible to have NiFi with user authentication but with SSL termination on NGINX. I have NGINX running on port 443 and a proxy_pass passing to nifi at port 8080. I played around with these headers:

```
X-ProxyScheme - the scheme to use to connect to the proxy
X-ProxyHost - the host of the proxy
X-ProxyPort - the port the proxy is listening on
X-ProxyContextPath - the path configured to map to the NiFi instance
```

But it seems impossible to get NiFi to recognise it's on https connection behind the proxy. I updated my auth configuration however NiFi still throws an error:

```
IllegalStateException: User authentication/authorization is only supported when running over HTTPS.. Returning Conflict response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User authentication/authorization is only supported when running over HTTPS
```

Basically https to nginx than to http port for nifi.

Comment: Using auth on nifi activates https. So, you have to direct requests to nifi https port.

Answer (score 2):

Am not familiar with NiFi, but on RHEL with nginx the below gives me a reverse proxy with a HTTPS connection terminated in nginx and an onward HTTP connection with a /abc_end_point.  Perhaps you can use this as a template?

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/tls/certs/abc.com.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/tls/private/abc.com.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
    proxy_send_timeout 7d;
    proxy_read_timeout 7d;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    location /abc_end_point {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/abc_end_point;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to setup Nifi with SSL offloading on the reverse proxy (nginx) - this kind of setup is not supported.
See: http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/Nifi-and-SSL-offloading-td7790.html#a7799

I recommended to use TLS (HTTPS) also between reverse proxy and Nifi.